# Ajax fail and get 504 error

Tags: plugins, ajax, forms

Help guys.. COntact form doesnt work and get 504 Gateway Time-out and ajax fail... what can i do?? Although message is sent.

I dont know exactly what to do.. Is there anyone with same problem and solve it?

Thats my js code that get error

```
    /**
  * Created by me664 on 12/29/14.
  */
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var old_order_id=false;

$('.btn-st-add-cart').click(function(){
    var me=$(this);
    var data = [];
    var holder=$('.message_box');
    var data1 = $('#form-booking-inpage').serializeArray();
    for(var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){
        data.push({
            name : data1[i].name,
            value : data1[i].value
        });
    }
    data.push({
        name : 'action',
        value : 'st_add_to_cart'
    });

    var dataobj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
        dataobj[data[i].name] = data[i].value;

    }

    me.addClass('loading');
    holder.html('');
    $.ajax({
        'type':'post',
        'dataType':'json',
        'url':st_params.ajax_url,
        'data':dataobj,
        'success':function(data){
            me.removeClass('loading');

            if(data.message){
                $.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        type: 'inline',
                        src: me.data('target')
                    },
                    close: function(){
                        old_order_id=false;
                    }

                });
                get_cart_detail(me.data('target'));
            }

            if(data.status){
                $.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        type: 'inline',
                        src: me.data('target')
                    },
                    close: function(){
                        old_order_id=false;
                    }

                });
                get_cart_detail(me.data('target'));
            }

        },
        error:function(data){
            me.removeClass('loading');
        }
    });
});

$('.btn-st-show-cart-modal').click(function(){
    var me = $(this);
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
            type: 'inline',
            src: me.data('target')
        },
        close: function(){
            old_order_id=false;
        }

    });
    get_cart_detail(me.data('target'));
});

function get_cart_detail(dom){
    // from 1.2.3
    var dom_div = dom + " " + " .booking-item-payment";
    var me = $(dom_div);
    $.ajax({
        'type':'post',
        'dataType':'json',
        'url':st_params.ajax_url,
        'data': {
            action : 'modal_get_cart_detail'
        },
        success: function(result){
            me.html(result);
        },
        error:function(data){
            // cosole.log("timquen")
        }
    });
}

$(document).on('click','.btn-st-checkout-submit',function(){
    var me = $(this).parents('.booking_modal_form');
    submit_form(me, $(this));
});

//$(document).on('click','.btn_hotel_booking',function(){
//    var form=$(this).closest('form');
//    if(!checkRequiredBooking(form)){
//        return false;
//    }
//
//    var tar_get=$(this).data('target');
//
//    $.magnificPopup.open({
//        items: {
//            type: 'inline',
//            src: tar_get
//        }
//
//    });
//
//});



function do_scrollTo(el)
{
    if(el.length){
        var top=el.offset().top;
        if($('#wpadminbar').length && $('#wpadminbar').css('position')=='fixed')
        {
            top-=32;
        }
        top-=300;
        $('html,body').animate({
            'scrollTop':top
        },500);
    }
}

function setMessage(holder,message,type)
{
    if(typeof  type=='undefined'){
        type='infomation';
    }
    var html='<div class="alert alert-'+type+'">'+message+'</div>';
    if(!holder.length) return;
    holder.html('');
    holder.html(html);
    console.log(holder.offset().top);
    console.log($(window).height());

    if(holder.offset().top>$(window).height()){
        do_scrollTo(holder);
    }
}


function checkRequiredBooking(searchbox)
{

    var dataobj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
        dataobj[data[i].name] = data[i].value;

    var holder=$('.search_room_alert');

    holder.html('');
    if(dataobj.room_num_search=="1"){
        if(dataobj.adult_number=="" || dataobj.child_number=='' ||typeof dataobj.adult_number=='undefined' || typeof dataobj.child_number=='undefined'){

            setMessage(holder,st_hotel_localize.booking_required_adult_children,'danger');
            return false;
        }

    }
    if(dataobj.check_in=="" || dataobj.check_out=='')
    {
        if(dataobj.check_in==""){
            searchform.find('[name=start]').addClass('error');
        }
        if(dataobj.check_out==""){
            searchform.find('[name=end]').addClass('error');
        }
        setMessage(holder,st_hotel_localize.is_not_select_date,'danger');
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

function submit_form(me,clicked){
    var button=clicked;
    var data = me.serializeArray();
    //var data1 = $('#form-booking-inpage').serializeArray();
    //for(var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){
    //    data.push({
    //        name : data1[i].name,
    //        value : data1[i].value
    //    });
    //}
    data.push({
        name : 'action',
        value : 'booking_form_direct_submit'
    });
    me.find('.form-control').removeClass('error');
    me.find('.form_alert').addClass('hidden');

    var dataobj = {};
    var form_validate=true;


    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
        dataobj[data[i].name] = data[i].value;

    }
    $('input,select,textarea', me).removeClass('error');
    $('input,select,textarea', me).each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
            form_validate = true;
        }
    });

    //term_condition
    if(!dataobj.term_condition){
        me.find('.form_alert').removeClass('hidden');
        me.find('.form_alert').html(st_checkout_text.accept_term);

        return false;
    }
    //console.log(dataobj);
    dataobj['order_id']=old_order_id;


    button.addClass('loading');
    $.ajax({
        'type':'post',
        'dataType':'json',
        'url':st_params.ajax_url,
        'data':dataobj,
        'success':function(data){
            button.removeClass('loading');

            if(data.message){
                me.find('.form_alert').addClass('alert-danger').removeClass('hidden');
                me.find('.form_alert').html(data.message);
            }

            if(data.redirect){
                window.location.href=data.redirect;
            }
            if(data.redirect_form){
                $('body').append(data.redirect_form);
            }

            if(typeof (data.order_id)!='undefined' && data.order_id)
            {
                old_order_id=data.order_id;
            }
            if(data.new_nonce)
            {
                $('#travel_order').val(data.new_nonce);
            }

            var widget_id='st_recaptchar_'+dataobj.item_id;

            get_new_captcha(me);
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert('Ajax Fail');

            var widget_id='st_recaptchar_'+dataobj.item_id;

            get_new_captcha(me);
            button.removeClass('loading');

        }
    });

    function get_new_captcha(me)
    {
        var captcha_box=me.find('.captcha_box');
        url=captcha_box.find('.captcha_img').attr('src');
        captcha_box.find('.captcha_img').attr('src',url);
    }
}

$('.payment-item-radio').on('ifChecked',function(){
    var parent=$(this).closest('li.payment-gateway');
    id=parent.data('gateway');
    parent.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('.st-payment-tab-content .st-tab-content[data-id="'+id+'"]').siblings().fadeOut('fast');
    $('.st-payment-tab-content .st-tab-content[data-id="'+id+'"]').fadeIn('fast');
});
});
```

Comment: That's a huge chunk of javascript code, it took me a while to find the AJAX call, and there's no PHP code showing the AJAX at the other end. Without the PHP it's not possible to reproduce the problem or diagnose what it is. Also what have you tried so far, and have you gotten any errors or warnings in your PHP error log?

Comment: jquery.js:4 XHR failed loading: POST "http://www.url.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php".
send @ jquery.js:4
ajax @ jquery.js:4
window.FormCraftSubmitForm @ form.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ form.min.js:1
dispatch @ jquery.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.js:3
 I go this... I tried to check js for errror but no success till now

Comment: thats the error i get

Comment: That's on the javascript end, but what about the PHP end? 504 is just a HTTP status code indicating something went wrong, we **need** to see the PHP code too, your question is currently impossible to answer